# How to get datalist's image src or id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, src, datalist

I try to get src or id of image in datalist using javascript.
Here is some of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.productImage').mouseover(function () {
                  var imageUrl = $('.productImage').attr('src');
                  //alert(imageUrl);
                  $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "WebServiceVar.asmx/getVarImage",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: "{'imageUrl':'" + imageUrl + "'}",
                     success: function (data) {
                     }
                  })
              });
          });
       </script>
```

When hovering over any image in datalist the alert(imageUrl) method displays only "images/products/image1.png", although there are multiple images in the DataList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below code this is helpful for you.

```
 var imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
```

If your mouseover event call with any image hover then current image src you have get using 'this' above code line.